# Can I get better performance out of this loop in 2012 Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, performance, loops, while-loop, geo

I'm writing a loop which takes a point from one table (where the U.S. state is also known) and sees what county the point intersects with (`#INPUT` has all of the point geographies and `[dbo].[counties]` has all the county geographies).

Here's the query:

```
DECLARE @RN_BEGIN INT
DECLARE @RN_END INT

SET @RN_BEGIN = 1
SELECT @RN_END = MAX([RN]) FROM #INPUT

DECLARE @STATE CHAR(2)
DECLARE @GEO GEOGRAPHY

WHILE @RN_BEGIN <= @RN_END

BEGIN

SELECT @ID_NUMBER = [ID_NUMBER] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
SELECT @STATE = [STATE] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
SELECT @GEO = [Geo] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN

INSERT INTO #OUTPUT
SELECT
@ID_NUMBER, 
CONCAT([statefp], [countyfp]) AS [FIPSTCNTY] 
FROM [dbo].[counties] 
WHERE @GEO.STIntersects([Geo]) = 1 AND [statefp] = @STATE

SET @RN_BEGIN = @RN_BEGIN + 1

END
```

For the table `#INPUT` (~1 million rows): I have a clustered index on `[ID_NUMBER]`, non-clustered index on `[RN]` (don't include any columns), and a spatial index on `[Geo]` (this is the point column).

For the table `#OUTPUT`(should be ~1 million rows when done): I have a clustered index on '[ID_NUMBER]`

For the table `[dbo].[counties]` (~3000 rows): I have a clustered index on the ID field (which was how it was brought in when I imported it), a non-clustered index on `[statefp]` (while including `[geo]` and `[countyfp]`), and a spatial index on `[Geo]` (this is the county column).

So my question to all of you is are there any blatant indexes that I'm missing or perhaps a new way to approach this problem (something other than a loop)? I know loops are slow (especially when it has to loop through ~1 million iterations) so I was hoping to speed this query up one way or the other.

Any suggestions/comments are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `@GEO.STIntersects([Geo])`?

Comment: @Dave.Gugg [STIntersects (geography data type)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933962.aspx) Returns 1 if a geography instance intersects another geography instance. Returns 0 if it does not.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I've never used geography before...  I think your answer is correct then.

Comment: @GarethD Thanks for your suggestion below. I've been thinking of things in loops recently and missed that join completely. Will I gain performance by making `[dbo].[counties]` smaller (i.e. Just the counties in Florida) and `#INPUT` smaller (i.e. just the lat/long points in Florida)?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty certain you can achieve this without a loop by just using a JOIN:

```
INSERT INTO #OUTPUT (ID_NUMBER, FIPSTCNTY)
SELECT  i.ID_NUMBER,
        FIPSTCNTY = CONCAT(c.statefp, c.countyfp)
FROM    dbo.counties AS c
        INNER JOIN #INPUT AS i
            ON i.GEO.STIntersects(c.Geo) = 1
            AND i.State = c.State;
```

With regard to indexes it is difficult to say without seeing the execution plan, but if you run this query in SSMS with "Include Actual Execution Plan" enabled, then it will suggest missing indexes, this is not an exact science but it is a pretty good place to start.

---

**BELOW THIS POINT SHOULD BE CONSIDERED A FOOT NOTE - I DO NOT ADVOCATE THE USE OF CURSORS WHERE THEY CAN BE AVOIDED**

I can't stress the above enough, I dislike the use of cursors as much as the next person, however, because people just use the default options 
they get an even worse reputation than they deserve and convoluted `WHILE` loops with temp tables usually perform worse than a properly declared 
cursor. It is this point I felt the need to address because it appears to be quite a common misconception.

In your case you are not modifying the data, and only reading forwards, so I would declare the cursor as `LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY`
to ensure it was only initialised with the capabilities I need:

```
DECLARE @STATE CHAR(2),
        @GEO GEOGRAPHY,
        @ID_NUMBER INT;

DECLARE InputCursor CURSOR LOCAL STATIC READ_ONLY FORWARD_ONLY
FOR
    SELECT  State, Geo, ID_NUmber
    FROM    #Input;

OPEN InputCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM InputCursor INTO @State, @Geo, @ID_NUMBER;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #OUTPUT
    SELECT  @ID_NUMBER, CONCAT([statefp], [countyfp]) AS [FIPSTCNTY] 
    FROM    [dbo].[counties] 
    WHERE   @GEO.STIntersects([Geo]) = 1 
    AND     [statefp] = @STATE;

    FETCH NEXT FROM InputCursor INTO @State, @Geo, @ID_NUMBER;
END

CLOSE InputCursor;
DEALLOCATE InputCursor;
```

Comment: I would add the `LOCAL` option too (since the default behavior depends on the `default to local cursor` database option). The cursor is only used in this SP and to be sure that it will be deallocated implicitly when the scope ends and all references are lost. (or close and deallocate the cursor manually).

Answer (score 0):

INSTEAD OF

```
SELECT @ID_NUMBER = [ID_NUMBER] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
SELECT @STATE = [STATE] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
SELECT @GEO = [Geo] FROM #INPUT WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
```

TRY

```
SELECT @ID_NUMBER = [ID_NUMBER],
       @STATE = [STATE], 
       @GEO = [Geo] 
FROM #INPUT 
WHERE [RN] = @RN_BEGIN
```

Comment: Never knew you could do that. Definitely will be incorporating that into my code from now on.

Answer (score 0):

iI think that you can eliminate the loop with something like:

```
INSERT INTO #OUTPUT
SELECT i.[ID_Number], CONCAT([statefp], [countyft]) as [FIPSTCNTY] 
FROM [dbo].[counties] c INNER JOIN #INPUT i ON i.[state] = c.[state]
WHERE i.[GEO].STIntersects(c.[GEO]) = 1
```

The other thing I would think is a big cost is the STIntersects clause. I don't know if SQL is using both indexes. You might be able to work around it like this person did here:

[slow spatial predicates (STContains, STIntersects, STWithin, ...)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6e1d7af4-ecc2-4d82-b069-f2517c3276c2/slow-spatial-predicates-stcontains-stintersects-stwithin-?forum=sqlspatial)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to eliminate the loop entirely.  I think your entire query block looks like it can be replaced with this:

```
INSERT INTO #OUTPUT
SELECT DISTINCT i.[ID_NUMBER], 
    CONCAT(c.[statefp], c.[countyfp]) AS [FIPSTCNTY] 
FROM [dbo].[counties] c
INNER JOIN #INPUT i
    ON  i.[Geo].STIntersects(c.[Geo]) = 1
    AND i.[STATE] = c.[statefp]
```

Obviously, run something like this to be sure you're getting what you want:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1000 i.[ID_NUMBER], 
    CONCAT(c.[statefp], c.[countyfp]) AS [FIPSTCNTY] 
FROM [dbo].[counties] c
INNER JOIN #INPUT i
    ON  i.[Geo].STIntersects(c.[Geo]) = 1
    AND i.[STATE] = c.[statefp]
```

Depending on your data and the relationship between `[counties]` and `#INPUT`, you may not need the `DISTINCT` qualifier.  It will be faster to leave it out if you know you don't need it, or (obviously) if you know you need the duplicates.  It would also be best to specify the field names for the insert table like `INSERT INTO #OUTPUT ([ID_NUMBER], [FIPSTCNTY])`, but I have no way of knowing what the names of those columns are.  However, if any of those are many-to-one, you may need it to avoid key violations.

Make sure you have spatial indexes on the geometry columns.  You should get a reasonable suggestion for missing indexes in SSMS if you generate the execution plan, too.  You may need to play around with the join, too.  I don't remember how well indexes play with each other; I haven't worked with geospatial or geometry for several years now.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar performance issues when using the SQL Server `STIntersects` function with my `geography` fields, which contained (sometimes complex) `POLYGON` shapes.

Adding a spatial index didn't make a difference, but here's the solution I came up with.

In my table, I added four new database fields, to store the minimum & maximum longitude and latitude values which that record's POLYGON covered.

[image]

To populate these fields, we need to get SQL Server to examine the POLYGON shapes.  Brace yourself, this isn't pretty...

```
UPDATE [County]
SET 
    County_Min_Longitude = cast(geometry::STGeomFromWKB([County_Polygon].STAsBinary(), [County_Polygon].STSrid).MakeValid().STEnvelope().STPointN(1).STX as numeric(12, 5)) ,
    County_Min_Latitude = cast(geometry::STGeomFromWKB([County_Polygon].STAsBinary(), [County_Polygon].STSrid).MakeValid().STEnvelope().STPointN(1).STY as numeric(12, 5)),
    County_Max_Longitude = cast(geometry::STGeomFromWKB([County_Polygon].STAsBinary(), [County_Polygon].STSrid).MakeValid().STEnvelope().STPointN(3).STX as numeric(12, 5)),
    County_Max_Latitude = cast(geometry::STGeomFromWKB([County_Polygon].STAsBinary(), [County_Polygon].STSrid).MakeValid().STEnvelope().STPointN(3).STY as numeric(12, 5))
```

Once we've run this query, our County records will all contain the original POLYGON, plus it's boundary.   But how does this help us ?

Well, now, when we have a point, and want to know if it intersects with each of our polygons, we can slip in some extra search criteria.

Here's (roughly) what your code would get changed to:

```
DECLARE 
    @longitude NUMERIC(15, 6) = 23.1238,
    @latitude NUMERIC(15, 6) = -5.3473

INSERT INTO #OUTPUT
SELECT @ID_NUMBER, 
       CONCAT([statefp], [countyfp]) AS [FIPSTCNTY] 
FROM [County] 
WHERE @longitude > [County_Longitude_Min]
AND @longitude < [County_Longitude_Max]
AND @latitude > [County_Latitude_Min]
AND @latitude < [County_Latitude_Max]
AND @GEO.STIntersects([County_Polygon]) = 1 AND [statefp] = @STATE
```

Using this code, SQL Server can *very quickly* eliminate any `[County]` records which our point definitely doesn't lie in, and then it'll just use `STIntersects` when our longitude & latitude values *do* lie within our area where this POLYGON lies.

For example, if I wanted to know if a position lay in the county of Devon, England, it's much more efficient to quickly check if the point lies within this rectangle, and if so, *then* use `STIntersects` to see if the position really is within this county.

[image: Devon]

In my in-house application, which was checking if a point lay in one of 330,000 POLYGONs, adding these four extra fields increased the speed from 45 seconds to under 1 second.